# Solr statistical information

Tags: solr

Is that possible to get some kind of stats from solr. E.g. Most frequently used words (unigrams), or phrases (bi- trigrams)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the schema browser (e.g. http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/schema.jsp), it gives you the top terms for any given field. You can also access this information with the [LukeRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) (e.g. http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/luke).

The [TermsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) also gives you information about indexed terms in a field and the number of documents that match each term.

The [StatsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent) gives you statististics about numeric fields.